# Automatically create SQS queue using localstack and docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, localstack

Is there any way to automatically create SQS Queus using localstack with docker-compose.yml?

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
      - "4571:4571"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=${SERVICES- }
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
      - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR- }
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
```

I would like to have some queues created when start docker-compose instead of create it manually.

Answer (score 24):

If you want to automatically bootstrap all needed queues on docker up,
you can add a shell script that will be run by localstack on docker container start.

Here is an example.

Add to your `volumes` the following:

```
- ./localstack_bootstrap:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/
```

Then add to the directory specified above (`localstack_bootstrap` in my case) a shell script with any name you like (I decided to call it `sqs_bootstrap.sh`) with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

# enable debug
# set -x

echo "configuring sqs"
echo "==================="
LOCALSTACK_HOST=localhost
AWS_REGION=eu-central-1

create_queue() {
    local QUEUE_NAME_TO_CREATE=$1
    awslocal --endpoint-url=http://${LOCALSTACK_HOST}:4566 sqs create-queue --queue-name ${QUEUE_NAME_TO_CREATE} --region ${AWS_REGION} --attributes VisibilityTimeout=30
}

create_queue "queue1"
create_queue "queue2"
```

Don't forget to run `chmod +x ./localstack_bootstrap/sqs_bootstrap.sh`.

More details on that I've found here - https://joerg-pfruender.github.io/software/docker/microservices/testing/2020/01/25/Localstack_in_Docker.html

Comment: perfect answer, thank you!

Comment: Many thanks for your work. By the way, the latest version (1.3 at present) states that `/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/` is now deprecated and to use `/etc/localstack/init/ready.d` instead.